# VBA to find and copy a column with specific header along with multiple adjacent columns to the right

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use VBA to find the `Sheet1` column header “`Country`”, and copy it along with the 20 columns to the right of it, to to `Sheet2` column A

I have tried:

```
Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, Col as Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Col = Application.Match("Country", Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1), 0)     
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lc = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
    With .Cells (lr, 20).Copy Destination:= Sheets("Sheet2"). Column (“A:A”)
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code, refactored and pointing out the issues in comments

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lr As Long
    'lc not used, left out
    Dim Col As Variant 'allow for possibility Country is not found
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ' Use the with block
        '   Sheets("Sheet1") may or may not be the same sheet as ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Col = Application.Match("Country", Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1), 0)
        Col = Application.Match("Country", .Rows(1), 0)

        ' Allow for possibility Country is not found
        If Not IsError(Col) Then
            ' Rows.Count refers to the ActiveSheet,
            '   which may or may not have the same number of rows as ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            ' You are also assuming that Column A has at least the number of rows as your data.
            '   Is this what you want?
            'lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            ' Specify the source range, starting at row 1, column containing Country
            '   then resize to the required size: lr rows, 21 columns
            ' Specify destination as top left cell, on the fully qualified sheet
            .Cells(1, Col).Resize(lr, 21).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)

            ' Alternative, if you don't need to copy formatting.
            'Dim r As Range
            'Set r = .Cells(1, Col).Resize(lr, 21)
            'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Resize(r.Rows.Count, r.Columns.Count).Value _ 
            '  = r.Value

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Uptick for the thorough explanations - in comparison my solution is extremely lazy lulz

Answer (score 1):

1. Find header with text **"Country"** (I'm assuming your header is in `Row 1`)
2. Once found, `Copy` the **"Country"** column and 19 columns to right
3. `Paste` in `Sheet2 A1`

---

```
Sub ColumnHunt()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim pr As Range: Set pr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") 'pr = Paste Range

Dim lr As Long, Found As Range
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set Found = ws.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find("Country")
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, Found.Column), ws.Cells(lr, Found.Column + 20)).Copy pr
    Else
        MsgBox "Country Column Not Found", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Using `.Find` without specifying some of the other parameters may give unexpected results, depending on how Find was last used [See here under Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144128)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: I am aware but those settings are spelled out for you in the syntax. Don’t want to take all the fun away from OP @chrisneilsen

Answer (score -1):

I hope my following code (with some comments) will help

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' Get the last Row Number of your Data
Dim myLastRow As Integer
myLastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Get the Column Number of your Header Name = "Country"
Dim myHeaderString As String
Dim myHeaderCell As Range
myHeaderString = "Country"
Set myHeaderCell = Sheet1.Rows(1).Find(What:=myHeaderString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

' Be sure that we find that column, send an error message if NOT
If Not myHeaderCell Is Nothing Then
    ' Get your Source Data Range
    Dim myColumnNo As Integer
    myColumnNo = myHeaderCell.Column
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, myColumnNo), Sheet1.Cells(myLastRow, myColumnNo + 20))

    ' Copy The Source Data Range
    Sheet1.Activate
    myRange.Copy

    ' Past to the Target location
    Sheet2.Activate
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).Select
    Sheet2.Paste

Else
        MsgBox "No Column Header found"
End If

End Sub
```